# Probability of A, Probability of B, Find either A or B

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, descriptive-statistics

The probability of dinning in Restaurant A is 0.55 while the probability of dinning in restaurant B is 0.35. 
The probability of dinning in both restaurants is 0.20. What is the probability of dinning in either restaurant A or B ?

**Progress**
No idea, how to do this. 
Need solution from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic probability question

$P(A \text{ or } B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \text{ and } B)$

Comment: so , my answer is 0.70 . I am not sure, if this correct. I used BODMAS formula for calculations 0.55+0.35-0.20 = 0.70

Comment: @AmandeepChawla Why are you unsure?

Answer (score 1):

This gets at something called the inclusion-exclusion principle. For two events, $A$ for dining in restaurant A and $B$ for dining in restaurant B:

$$P(A\text{ or } B)=P(A) + P(B) - P(A\text{ and } B)$$

(The formula for $n$ events is given in the Wikipedia page on inclusion-exclusion. Read it if you get the hiccups and need a scare.)

The intuition is that $P(A)+P(B)$ may overshoot $P(A\text{ or } B)$, so we subtract out some probability to correct that overshoot. That correction is the overlap of $A$ and $B$, which has been counted twice, once by $P(A)$ and then again by $P(B)$, so we subtract out the overlap.

I encourage you to draw a Venn diagram of this. I will post one in an edit to this (I already owe someone another edit to a different post of mine, so I know I’ll be editing CV posts this weekend), but you’ll learn more if you try the Venn diagram yourself.

**EDIT**

Let's look at a picture. Purple is the overlap of blue and red.

[image]

In this picture, since purple counts towards both red and blue, $P(red) = 0.5$. Likewise, $P(blue) = 0.5$.

$$P(\text{red}) + P(\text{blue}) = 0.5 + 0.5 = 1$$

But hold on...a quarter of the rectangle is neither blue nor red.

So we subtract out the overlap of blue and red, $P(\text{blue and red})$, to get the probability of being blue or red, $P(\text{blue or red})$:

$$P(\text{blue or red}) = P(\text{red}) + P(\text{blue}) - P(\text{blue and red})= 0.5 + 0.5 - 0.25 = 0.75$$

"Inclusion-exclusion" comes from the fact that we include (double count) the overlap, and then we exclude (subtract out) one copy of the overlap.